# using a reducer slows the mapper

Tags: hadoop, io, mapreduce

When I set the number of reducers to zero, the map phase finishes quite fast (~10 mins). 
However, when I set the number of reducers to more than 1, the time that the map phase needs (exactly the same mapper code), increases dramatically (I stop it after ~30mins, while it still is at 20%). The first map tasks in the queue reach 100% and then the process stucks.

Any intuition? Is it the case that when no reducer is used map output goes straight to disk, while when a reduce phase is used the map output goes to a memory buffer?

A pseudocode of my main mapper loop is the following:

```
for (VIntWritable e1 : D2entities) {                    
    for (VIntWritable e1 : D1entities) {    
       output.collect(e1, e2);
    }           
}
```

In both cases I use `conf.setCompressMapOutput(true)` and `conf.set("mapred.reduce.slowstart.completed.maps", "1.00");`. When I use a reducer, I also set:

```
conf.setOutputKeyClass(VIntWritable.class);     
conf.setOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);       

conf.setMapOutputKeyClass(VIntWritable.class);
conf.setMapOutputValueClass(VIntWritable.class);
```

otherwise, I use:

```
conf.setOutputKeyClass(VIntWritable.class);     
conf.setOutputValueClass(VIntWritable.class);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set the number of reducers to 0, you are doing a map only job. This means that the data won't be sorted nor shuffled and the output of the mappers will be written directly to disk. However, if you use reducers, then you have two cases: when you only need to sort the data, and when you also need to perform some aggregation or some operations with the data.

If you only need to sort the data, you can go with the identity reducer, which will sort the data, perform the shuffle, feed it to the reducers and then writing it to disk. In the second case, the reducers take extra time to perform the operations you wish to do, wether it's aggregation or any other thing.

So yes, there is a big difference in time when doing a map only job, and when also writing a reduce phase. Consider the following picture, all the steps you don't have to go through if after the map you write it directly to disk:

[image: map reduce phases]

**EDIT:** when adding a reduce phase, you see that the mappers reach 100% but don't appear as completed because there is some presorting being done during the map phase for efficiency reasons, also making some buffering writes in memory. Therefore, when you wrote your job as map only, this was not done and it completed much faster. However, now that you also use a reducer, once it reaches 100% of the mapper, it starts with the presorting and buffering in memory, and it does not appear as "Completed" until this is done.

[image: map side]

Hope it is more clear now!

Comment: I agree. My problem is, though, that the same **map** task, before the reduce phase even starts, takes too long when I set the number of reducers to more than zero! I have, say, 250 mappers in the queue and 50 of them run at the same time. When these reach 100%, they do not even get the "complete" status.

Comment: Oh ok, now I understood better your question, sorry for that. Please see my edit.

Comment: Yes, much clearer now, thanks! I will wait a bit before accepting your answer

Comment: I'm really glad it helped you!